# Run long operation when Property Changed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, async-await, task-parallel-library

How can I run some long operation, when my property raises PropertyChanged event?
Example:

```
class SomeClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableConllection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public string Path
    {
         get => _path;
         if (_path != value) {
             _path = value;
             OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Path));
             // await Task.Run(()=> long operation, for example load some Items use "_path");
    }
}
```

Property can't be async and I think it is "normal". But what should I do?
I think that such a case occurs often.

Comment: You could plug into the property changed event and perform your async task there

Comment: IMHO if setting a property needs to kick of a long running method in the background you should think of converting it to a method and name it properly. I would not expect a sideeffect like this.  Anyway, what happens if the values changes in a fast sequence. You will have to abort the running task or not? You have to think about that as well.

Comment: Try moving the same to event .eg. Loading , user events or something and make that event async

Answer (score 2):

You should read Stephen Cleary's MSDN article about asynchronous data-bound properties where he defines a "task watcher" class called `NotifyTaskCompletion<T>` that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and has a `Result` property that you can bind to:

**Async Programming : Patterns for Asynchronous MVVM Applications: Data Binding:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Path
    {
        get { return _path; }
        set
        {
            if (_path != value)
            {
                _path = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Path));
                AsyncProperty = new NotifyTaskCompletion<int>(YourAsyncMethod());
            }
        }
    }

    public NotifyTaskCompletion<string> AsyncProperty { get; private set; }
}
```

---

```
<Label Content="{Binding AsyncProperty.Result}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Task.Run` without `await`. It may or may not work well depending on the case, there is no universal answer regarding that.

You can create a method like this to set the value, it is a more sure way to do this. However if you need a databinding this can't work:

```
public async Task SetPath(string value)
{
     if (_path != value) {
         _path = value;
         OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Path));
         await Task.Run(()=> ...);
}
```

If you need data binding and want to use `await`, then it is usually the best practice to use debouncing with Timer - you don't want some expensive operation to be available without restriction to the user so that he can freeze or crash the app.

Comment: Yes, problem that I need binding.

Comment: As said, Task.Run in get won't cause any problem by itself. I'll add one more option for using Timer.